# Simplepie not recognising wordpress RSS

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, blogger, simplepie

```
$feed->set_feed_url(array('http://chrisheadleand.com', 'http://glaciem-world.com/feed/'));
$feed->set_autodiscovery_level(SIMPLEPIE_LOCATOR_ALL);
```

Is there any reason in simplepie why these domains wont parse into a HTML page? The only RSS I seam to be able to get simplepie to work with so far is the twitter RSS feeds

eg

```
 http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=thenextweb
```

I need to get this working (with autodetect) for rss feeds from wordpress and blogger websites..

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

CJ

---

Update

I figured out how to get the error messages from sinmplepie

I'm now getting the follwoing information

http://www.clearthemist.com/test/

Can anyone explain what this means and how I can fix it.

The url I'm using is http://chrisheadleand.com - It works fine on simplepies web demo but not on my site. I have tried two different versions of simplepie with no better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer to this one is that there seams to be a problem with simplepie if the header information in the RSS feed is slightly unconventional. I unstalled the latest version of wordpress and it worked fine.

Cheers for reading!